# How to get outlook email message MIME content using Graph client C#

Tags: c#, outlook, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

How to get outlook email message MIME content using Graph client C#
like in EWS call
byte [] MesageBlob = EmailMessage.MimeContent.Content;
and .eml file name

Answer (score 0):

Even though Outlook does not save messages in MIME format, there are two ways you can get an Outlook message body in MIME format:

- You can append a `$value` segment to a `get-message` operation on that message.

  ```
  GET /users/{id}/messages/{id}/$value
  ```
- If the message is attached to an Outlook item or group post, you can append a `$value` segment to a get-attachment operation on that item or group post.
  In either case, your app must have the [appropriate permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#mail-permissions) to access the Outlook item or group post in order to apply the get-message or get-attachment operation.

  ```
  GET /users/{id}/events/{id}/attachments/{id}/$value
  ```

Read more about that in the [Get MIME content of a message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-get-mime-message) article.

Comment: Thanks for reply !!
Need this functionality using Graph client in C#

Comment: Have you been able to solve this? I have been trying to solve this but I'm stuck.